# Install Elasticsearch with HELM on EKS Cluster got Error unknown setting [node.data] please check that any required plugins are installed

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Can u help me about elasticsearch, I'm using helm chart to install elasticsearch on EKS Cluster (AWS).
this error log:

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-04-04T06:51:37.598Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"no plugins loaded", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-2","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-04-04T06:51:37.764Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/nvme1n1)]], net usable_space [29.3gb], net total_space [29.4gb], types [ext4]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-2","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-04-04T06:51:37.764Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"heap size [128mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-2","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-04-04T06:51:37.780Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"node name [elasticsearch-master-2], node ID [UVdphx_mRxed9bUS5sKU-A], cluster name [elasticsearch], roles [data_cold, ingest, data_frozen, ml, data_hot, transform, data_content, data_warm, master, remote_cluster_client, data]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.node.Node","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-2","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-04-04T06:51:45.670Z", "log.level":"ERROR", "message":"uncaught exception in thread [main]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-master-2","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException","error.message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [node.data] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings","error.stack_trace":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [node.data] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings\n\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:563)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:509)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:479)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:449)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:151)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:56)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:447)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:284)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:234)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:234)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:358)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:157)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:81)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:122)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)\nFor complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log\n"}
uncaught exception in thread [main]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [node.data] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:563)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:509)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:479)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:449)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:151)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:56)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:447)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:284)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:234)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:234)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:358)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:157)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
For complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log
```

im not edit values.yaml (default)

Answer (score 1):

More info are needed, but I think you are using version 8 which has made 'node.data' attribute obsolete.
You can replace it by :

```
node.roles: <master|data>
```